# how to quickly locate the function which firstly returns a specific error code in gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Assume I have a long call-stack. My upper level function returns a error code such as `ERROR_INTERNAL`(it's int type). I can see many `return ERROR_INTERNAL;` in source code, but don't know which one generate current error.

I debug it with gdb, and want to quickly know which down-level function is the first one to throw this error. I'm not familiar with the code, and I don't have time to delve into it.

Anyone who knows how to use gdb functions such as conditional breakpoints to locate the function ?

Comment: Don't the application have any kind of logging? "Internal errors" should really be reported, in great detail, using some kind of logging. If it isn't, then it's a rather big flaw in the application, one that needs to be fixed.

Comment: As for the problem of catching those returns in a debugger, you could use a terminal (or the built-in "find" feature in your IDE) to find all `return ERROR_INTERNAL;` locations. Then you have their file-names and line-numbers, and can use them to add breakpoints in the debugger.

Comment: I don't know how to trace all function returns in GDB, but other tools can. `dtrace` can trace `pid$target:::return` , and `ltrace` has the  `-x @MAIN` option. Run them and look for the first function that returns (the numerical value of) ERROR_INTERNAL.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the team members may not choose print whereever the error occurs.